# Siddhi override eventTimestamp

Tags: wso2, siddhi

I have following Source in WSO2 Siddhi CEP:

```
@source(type='kafka',
    topic.list='userInfo',
    partition.no.list='0',
    threading.option='single.thread',
    group.id="threadAccessor",
    bootstrap.servers='localhost:9092',
    @map(type='json', @attributes(USERID = '$.USERID', tst = '$.TST', ACTIVITY = '$.ACTIVITY', AVG_HBR = '$.AVG_HBR')))
define stream SweetProductionStream (USERID string, tst long, ACTIVITY string, AVG_HBR int);
```

Is there a way to override value returned by function `eventTimestamp()` using mapping ? Is is possible at all ? 
I know that it is for `externalTimeWindow`, but I would like to use my own timestamps for pattern finding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Event's timestamp is immutable, you can only access its timestamp with `eventTimestamp()`. If you need to use your own timestamp then have it as an attribute in the stream and use that.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve in the source. You can pass the timestamp in the message and extract that, and use that as an attribute. You can pass this attribute when processing externalTimeWindow, and also when using patterns you can use the attribute and define time base conditions along with others.

Comment: Yeah, I know about `externalTimeWindow` but I haven't seen any info about time base conditions for pattern matching.